# Replace ng-view html content in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form inside ng-view, which get submit with $http call, i get html in response of the form submit. I want to replace ng-view content with the response html. Is it possible?

`formSubmit($event, <action_url>)` is value of form ng-submit attribute

```
// controller
$scope.formSubmit = function (e, action) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(e.currentTarget),
            data = null,
            submitBtn = form.find('button[type=submit]');
        if(!validate.form(form)) {
            console.log('form validation failed..!!');
            return false;
        }
        data = form.serialize();
        data += '&'+submitBtn.attr('name') +'='+ submitBtn.attr('value');
        $http({
            'method': 'post',
            'url': action+'&format=ng',
            'data': data,
            'headers' : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // HERE I WANT TO PUT `data` IN NG-VIEW
        });
    }
```

---

```
// Form
<form method="post" id="RegistrationForm" name="RegistrationForm" ng-submit="formSubmit($event,'<MY_URL>')" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-row   required ">
            <label for="profile_customer_email">
                <span>Email*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="input-text email required valid" autocomplete="off" id="profile_customer_email" type="text" name="profile_customer_email" value="" maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you show us the view? This code is... unusual. What is the reason for you not binding $scope variables to your form controls? If you come from a jQuery background than in short this is not how you handle forms in angular.

Comment: i know, actually the thing is that this application is not being build from scratch, i'm just implementing angularJS in this. i don't have json response to use in model. I get html as response, which i need to dump in view

Comment: with view you mean the html response or the form?

Comment: Well nevermind I just wanted to make sure you are not doing something overly complicated. In that case if you get html back you don't have many options, i can only think of ng-bind-html-unsafe (it might have been removed in recent versions, not sure, so you might have to code around that)

Comment: Or maybe it would be possible to put the html in the $templateCache and use it as normal view? Dunno...

Comment: you are suggesting something like this <div ng-view ngBindHtml="something"></div>

Comment: Well, either ng-bind-html-unsafe _or_ ng-view. But, honestly I'm just thinking outloud. I have no idea if that would work the way you want.